# Monitor network traffic using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to monitor the traffic which is due to background JS files of different extensions. I have developed an extension which monitors traffic which is due to content script JS files of different extensions. But it is failing to capture traffic of background JS Files.

Can this be possible to monitor the traffic which is due to background JS files ?

Comment: I'm unsure if that's possible because of the strict security. But you might try to check if your extension can access the background page via extension id's, chrome-extension://lphdoefbooasdlpaobcjasdcjnekobin/background.html , but loading them might crash the other extensions.

Comment: Thanks, But really not sure about this, how we can read other extension's B/G page, also what if extension do not have one ?
Even if I read the B/G page of some extension, how this will enable to read the request which are issued by the that extension. Can you please elaborate ?